# How to determine if a profile already has a password set within a Journy Decision node

Tags: kademi

I would like to set up a decision in a Journey that determines if the current profile has a password set.

Using Decision node and selecting Rules, there does not appear to be an option to look up a password column.

Here's my journey.
https://spinsurance.admin.kademi.com.au/funnels/email-new-policy-holder-users/version1/#journeyBuilder-tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a custom journey field. As an example, Add the code to a custom app under /APP-INF/:

```
controllerMappingList.addTextJourneyField('profileHasProfile', 'Profile Has Password', 'checkProfilePassword');

function checkProfilePassword(profile) {
    var userResource = applications.userApp.findUserResource(profile);
    if( formatter.isNotNull(userResource) ){
        return userResource.isHasPassword();
    }

    return 'false';
}
```

Then  you can use that field with an `equals` operator

Comment: @stephen.fueldesign add to your custom app server js :)

Comment: @anhnt thanks. I placed into /WEB-INF/ folder. How do I make use of the newly created JourneyField? I was looking under Rules link within my Decision node, but it's not showing. Do I need to re-index or anything?

Comment: @stephen.fueldesign /WEB-INF/ folder contains code for that website only. You have to create new custom app and put into /APP-INF/ and enable that app at account level

Answer (score 1):

Normally journeys need to take action when the user sets a password, or doesnt after a timeout. You can do that with the "Created credentials" goal, rather then a decision node

[image: screenshot showing the goal]

The previous answers are correct if you do actually need a decision